# Data set with known camera parameters

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images

I am looking for a data set containing images of pedestrians/cyclists with a static backgrounds and given camera calibration information (intrinsic and extrinsic) for a scene. I have already found EPFL and UvA Multi-Person Tracking from Overlapping Cameras Benchmark Dataset, but need something else.